# Reference a file input in its corresponding typescript file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Given a file input such as:

```
<input type="file" #fileInput>
```

I am looking for a way to reference this file input in my typescript file to perform a click on it.
For this purpose, I have introduced the following code:

```
 @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput!: ElementRef;
 
 ... some observable changes its value and I call:
 this.fileInput.click();
```

The problem is that the ViewChild does not seem to be recognized as a file input, since I am presented the error: `TypeError: this.fileInput.click is not a function`.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: ok, just figured out what's going on here: I need to address the `nativeElement`, meaning instead of calling `this.fileInput.click()`, I have to call `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()`.

Answer (score -1):

when you want to perform this action?
if you want use this command in ngOnInit this error appear for you.
you can use it on ngAfterViewInit or use it on setTimeOut for delay like this

`setTimeout(() => { this.fileInput.click(); }, 500);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).